# Matplotlib: How to render only a small region of a larger figure (clip)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to draw a contour plot. In a second step I would like to extract a small region from that plot and draw it in a new axis.

The closest I could find, was a tutorial to clip an image: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_clip_path.html

But I did not find a way to clip a patch from a figure.

Here's the code to create the contour plot:
(based on this example : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html )

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
plt.plot(-2, 2.5, 'or')
plt.show()
```

The attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se417.png) shows the kind of figure I would like to produce: A new figure with the same bounding box as the original figure, but only a small patch around a known position is drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN values in `z` are not displayed. Hence all you need to do, is define the clip path, and then determine which (x, y) values fall outside that path and set the corresponing `z` values to NaN.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01) # need higher resolution to get nice clipping boundaries
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y) # need dense meshgrid for contains_points
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)

patch = plt.Circle((-2, 2), 1) # circle with radius 1 around the point (-2, 2)
path = patch.get_path().transformed(patch.get_patch_transform()) # the path attribute of Circle has to be transformed to data units
is_valid = path.contains_points(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
z[~is_valid] = np.nan # NaN values are not plotted

h = plt.contourf(xx,yy,z)

plt.plot(-2, 2.5, 'or')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works fine and solves my problem.

Comment: @user3224103 Happy to help. If it solves your problem, then [you should accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).